# How to append a key/value in react state object (Functional Component)

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I have a state

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState({});
```

I want to append a key/value to object while also **preserving the key/value that I have push before**

This doesn't work:

```
array.map((value, index) => {  // consider array has some data
    setOptions({...options, [index]: value})
});
```

So for example lets say that I've pushed {0: "Zero"}
Next time I push {1: "One"} it should preserver {0: "Zero"}

Comment: Please try to remote []. i.e. setOptions({...options, index: value})

Answer (score 0):

To do this action you need to fetch old data first and store it in variable, and do your updates and then set options again:

for example:

```
let tempOptions = options;
array.map((value, index) => {  // consider array has some data
    tempOptions[index] = value;
});
setOptions(tempOptions);
```

You can do that in another way like this:

```
setOptions(prev => {...prev, newValue});
```

always remember you are work on state, and you cant update state direct and keep careful from a lot of states update...

Answer (score 0):

try to add the new values in new object and then you set one time setOptions.Don't try to setOptions in an array map.

```
var newOptions = {}
array.map((value, index) => {  // consider array has some data
    newOptions[index] =  value
});
setOptions({...options, ...newOptions})
```